# Get access token with react-native-google-signin

Tags: react-native, google-contacts-api

I need for my application to find user contacts from gmail. So I need to use this api from [google contacts api](https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3#retrieving_all_contacts)

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{userEmail}/full
```

When I send a GET request to this url I get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

My question is how can I get the accessToken to request this api with **react-native-google-signin**? I've already tried

```
GoogleSignin.getCurrentUser().then(infos => console.log(infos));
```

I get with this function user informations as name, photo, email... and I get a field `idToken` but when I add this token to my header request I get always code 403, so I think that isn't the access token.

Can you please help me to find access token or is there any other solution to find contacts directly with  react-native-google-signin

**Edit:**
Also tried

```
GoogleSignin.getTokens().then((res) => { console.log(res); });
```

but nothing is logged I don't know why

Answer (score 3):

You can get the accessToken by calling [GoogleSignIn.getTokens()](https://github.com/react-native-community/google-signin#gettokens) method after signing in using [GoogleSignIn.signIn()](https://github.com/react-native-community/google-signin#signin). Then you can attach the returned `accessToken` to the `Bearer` header when sending a `GET` request to https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full.

**Warning:** The Google Contacts API **is now deprecated** and is scheduled for sunset on June 15, 2021. Apps should instead use the [People API](https://developers.google.com/people). Get started with the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/people/contacts-api-migration). See the [official statement](https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3/announcement).

Answer (score -1):

you can try this function it work fine with me

```
_signIn = async () => {
    try {
        await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
        const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();

                response: {
                    first_name: userInfo.user.givenName,  
                    social_id: userInfo.user.id, last_name: userInfo.user.familyName, email: userInfo.user.email
                }

            // console.log('_signIn userInfo', userInfo);


    } catch (error) {
        if (error.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
            // console.log('_signIn error.code 1', error.code);
            // user cancelled the login flow
        } else if (error.code === statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS) {
            // console.log('_signIn error.code 2 ', error.code);
            // operation (f.e. sign in) is in progress already
        } else if (error.code === statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
            // console.log('_signIn error.code 3', error.code);
            // play services not available or outdated
        } else {
            // console.log('_signIn else', error);
            // some other error happened
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you read the question? I need gmail contacts or accessToken

Comment: i think you can find the access token in google sign in response